# Why does my loop condition not work by comparing a variable to itself?

Tags: javascript

```
var text = "dave kdfkdf dave kdfkdfffff dave";
var myName = "dave";
var hits = new Array();

var counter;
var nameCounter;


for (counter = 0; counter <= text.length; counter++){
    if (text[counter] === myName[0]) {
        for (nameCounter=counter; nameCounter < (nameCounter+myName.length); nameCounter++) {
            hits.push(text[nameCounter]);
        }
    }
}
```

the code above does not work, but when I change the condition of the second loop to:

```
nameCounter < (counter+myName.length);
```

then it does work.

can you explain, why? thanks :)

Comment: Why would you expect the first one to work?  No matter what value I may pick for x, it will always be true that x < x +4

Comment: @adeneo ha ha actually my comment was wrong too :)

Comment: thanks, sometimes the answers is so obvious. the x<x+2 comment just made it clear. sorry for the stupid question and thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple math.
I understand myName can be any name, with any length, but let's stick with "dave" and length of 4 and change myName.length to the hard-coded value of 4:

we're left with the following as the condition for your loop. it's never false, thus never stops*...

```
nameCounter < nameCounter + 4
```

*well, until it overflows, or run out of memory, etc.